# Converted MP4 not playing in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I recently converted a file from `.avi` to `.mp4` using the Free MP4 Video Converter (v. 5.0.28 build 827) from DVDVideoSoft. I tried opening the new MP4 file in Chrome. I can hear the audio from the file but none of the video appears.

According to VLC, it was encoded by Lavf54.59.107 and the decoded format is 4:2:0 YUV.

I tried using the "Disable hardware-accelerated video decode" under `chrome://flags` but it did not solve the issue. I'm using Chrome 29.0.1547.66 on a Windows Vista computer if that information would help at all.

Comment: MP4 is a container and can contain video and audio using various codecs.  In VLC choose Media Information from the menu, click on Codec Details and expand the streams.  Verify that the video codec is H.264.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, Chrome does not support whatever video codec you used. Current versions of Chrome support Theora, H. 264, and WebM. Most likely your converter either copied or reencoded to a Xvid video stream, which Chrome doesn't support. Note that MP4 is just the container format, it is capable of containing a number of different video and audio codecs.